# Samba share accessible on Windows after SSH connection established via Cygwin?

Tags: ssh, windows-7, samba, file-sharing, workgroup

So I have an unusual problem that I have been fighting with for literally weeks now.

Let me establish the following prior to elaboration:

- The Samba server is running Ubuntu Server 16.04
- All the client machines are Windows 7
- All of the Windows clients connect by a single user (Stupid for security I know but it was out of troubleshooting).

So, I have a Samba share setup so that all the clients can view/read/execute/blah blah the files within said share. (The next part is sort of like the age old question of "What came first? The chicken or the egg?") I mapped the share as a drive in Windows 7. I can *not* even view the mapped drive unless I make some sort of direct connection into the Ubuntu server itself. In this case, I use Cygwin to establish an SSH connection into the server from any one of the Windows 7 client computers. Once I send the SSH connection to the server, the Samba share is accessible and all of the share's contents can be used and everything is all groovy.

If I reboot the client that I made the SSH connection from, the Samba share is no longer accessible UNTIL I make another SSH connection.

I'm not questioning SSH here specifically, this is just what I use in order to edit /etc/samba/smb.conf.

- I have opened the Samba port in iptables and made the rule persistent
- I have added "server signing = auto" to the smb.conf file as mentioned [here](https://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/213344-samba-share-not-accessible-windows-7-client-2.html#post2431832)
- I have set the parameter in LPO on one of the local Windows machines mentioned [here](https://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/213344-samba-share-not-accessible-windows-7-client-2.html#post2485684) to "ALLOW ALL"
- I have made the the "security" parameter set to "ADS" and "domain"

None of these have done squat. At this point, I am confused as to whether or not this has anything to do with the Samba server but merely the Windows clients.

The following smb.conf parameters have been shortened to include all of the parts that were I have tampered with out since I installed Samba in the first place.

```
    [global]

    ## Browsing/Identification ###

    # Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of
    security = ADS
    workgroup = [wkgp]

    ####### Authentication #######

    server role = auto

    [share]
    path = /home/[user]/[share]
    valid users = [user]
    read only = no
    browseable = yes
    create mask = 0644
    directory mask = 0755
    server signing = auto
    hostname lookups = yes
    hosts allow = 192.168.X.
    public = yes
    force user = [user]
```

Please let me know if there is anything else needed in order to better understand the problem. Keep in mind, I am using local machine logins on the Windows clients and a workgroup.

Also, whenever I run "smbclient -L localhost -U [user]", I get the following:

> session setup failed: NT_STATUS_NO_LOGON_SERVERS

Comment: This is a regular workgroup without a domain controller, correct?

Comment: @Terrance That is correct.

Comment: OK, remove the security = ADS as that has to deal with domain computers.  I will add an answer here quickly.

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `security = ADS` from your file, then in the `[global]` section of your `/etc/samba/smb.conf` file add the following lines:

```
[global]

usershare owner only = false
unix extensions = no
follow symlinks = yes
wide links = yes

ntlm auth = no
lanman auth = no
client ntlmv2 auth = yes
guest ok = yes
acl allow execute always = true
```

If it is a share that you are allowing all computers on your network to access, you might want to setup the share like the following:

```
[storage]
   path = "/media/storage"
   directory mask = 0777
   writeable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   admin users = terrance
```

Then restart your samba server

```
systemctl restart smbd.service
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Are you recommending that I emulate the exact parameters that you listed under the share part? Like removing everything else and keeping only those parameters you have listed above?

Comment: @Brandon No, you can keep the other settings but you might want to test each one after changing them and restarting the samba again.  It all depends on how you want to run it.  On my home network that works fine for my other systems to get right on my shares without having to log in, etc.

Comment: Okay. So I set the parameters and the Windows client machine spit back an error in Explorer saying "Microsoft Windows Network: Location resource already in use" or something to that effect and would not allow me to view the share. In order to get the share back up and viewable, I had to comment out all the changes that you recommended. Any ideas?

Comment: @Brandon You might want to kill any shares you have open on your Windows first, then add the changes to the Ubuntu server, restart the service, then reconnect the Windows.  Also, the settings I put in the global section do not have to be exactly what I put, you can try yes/no or true/false except for the acl line as that one handles a bug with executing files on a samba share in Windows.

Comment: I read somewhere about having to add the Windows users' accounts to the Samba share. Is this true?

Comment: You shouldn't have to as you can have the mounting of the share save the username and password you are connecting to it as.

Comment: So after trial and error, I noticed that the "ntlm auth" option is what breaks the connection. Have any leads on this? Any where I can start poking around Windows in?

Comment: Maybe have a look at https://www.samba.org/samba/docs/current/man-html/smb.conf.5.html